# How to get images from Google Cloud Storage and show them in <img> tag using Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-storage

In one of my Laravel based Application, I want to show user images that are stored **Google Cloud Storage**. After some processing, I got the image URL as `gs://< my_custom_domain >/customer/images/< custom_id >/0f393ee5ab484771338268d58d08f5c1.jpg`

This is not a URL that can access directly!!

But I don't find a way to use that URL to get the image from **Google Cloud Storage** and also have no idea about how to show that image in  tag.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think that Cloud Storage Tools API can be useful for you, due to provides some methods that you can use to serve images files.
Based in the documentation about [Serving Images](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/images), I think you can use:

```
$options = ['size' => 400, 'crop' => true];
$image_file = "gs://${my_bucket}/image.jpg";
$image_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($image_file, $options);
```

You can also check this [GitHub link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/6d6757ee1df71e22ded52c2c78edf58786a99961/appengine/php55/storage/app.php) to see more code examples about Cloud Storage using PHP.
Hope this was useful for you!